# Alternative to catching and rethrowing exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I came across the need to do this:

```
try:
    prop_file = next(file for file in os.listdir(data_folder) if 'property' in file)
except StopIteration:
    raise StopIteration('The property file could not be found in the specified folder ({})!'.format(data_folder))
```

which seems kinda silly because I am catching an exception only to re-throw it but this time with a more *information-rich* feedback.

Are there alternatives to this, or is this considered a standard practice?

Comment: It is extremely unusual to pass an explicit argument to `StopIteration`, and moderately unusual to explicitly throw `StopIteration` at all. In the normal cases where Python catches `StopIteration`, the argument isn't even treated as an exception message; it's used as the expression value for a `yield from` expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StopIteration` doesn't look like the right thing to throw.

In this case you can make `next` return `None`.

```
prop_file = next((file for file in os.listdir(data_folder)
                  if 'property' in file), None)
if not prop_file:
    message = 'The property file could not be found in the specified folder ({})!'
    raise AppropriateException(message.format(data_folder))
```

Comment: Also, if you don't actually need the name of the property file, but are just checking it exists, you could say `if not any('property' in file for file in ...`

Answer (score 1):

The only tweak I would suggest would be to chain these with a `from` clause in the `raise`. In the current set-up the exception traceback points to the `raise` statement when you might want to inform the user/developer from which *exact* line the error originated from (think of a case where the body of the `try` contains many statements).

You could add the small tweak:

```
try:
    prop_file = next(file for file in os.listdir(data_folder) if 'property' in file)
except StopIteration as e:
    msg = 'The property file could not be found in the specified folder ({})!'
    raise StopIteration(msg.format(data_folder)) from e
```

Other than that, I've personally seen no other alternatives to this in the wild and even though I can't say it is "standard" it isn't a bad thing to do, you always want your exceptions to be informative.

Comment: I made a context manager to use with `with` blocks to re-raise exceptions with richer messages, or as a more appropriate exception.

Comment: @PeterWood That's definitely an alternative and you could post it as an answer, it seems like a nice thing to do if required more than once.